# C# XPath not selects some child nodes

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xmldocument

I'm trying to use the XPath expression: `.//*[@class='newsContent newsClosed']/b`, but it is not working, always returns 0 elements.

I then tried to change the expression on `.//*[@class='newsContent newsClosed']`, and it's work.

Why first expression does not work?

I'm using `XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode` for retrieve elements.

Part of XHTML:

```
<div class="newsContent newsClosed">
    <b>some text that I need to take</b>
    <br />
    <p>
        text
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>text</b>
        <br />
        <b>text</b>
        <b>text</b>
    </p>
...
```

In FirePath both expressions are working properly.

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. You claim this is XHTML, so the issue is most likely that you haven't specified the namespace for `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is XHTML, then you need to specify the *namespace* of your element: `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`.

```
var resolver = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());

resolver.AddNamespace("html", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");

var result = doc.SelectSingleNode(
    ".//*[@class='newsContent newsClosed']/html:b", resolver);
```

My personal preference would be to ditch XPath altogether and use LINQ to XML:

```
XNamespace html = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";

var result = (string) doc.Descendants()
    .Where(element => (string) element.Attribute("class") == "newsContent newsClosed")
    .Elements(html + "b")
    .Single();
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FiJqNd) for a demo.